# Find highest and lowest selling item in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables as follows--

`ORDERS`

```
  create table orders (
  ono      number(5) not null primary key,
  cno      number(5) references customers,
  eno      number(4) references employees,
  received date,
  shipped  date);
```

`ODETAILS`

```
create table odetails (
  ono      number(5) not null references orders,
  pno      number(5) not null references parts,
  qty      integer check(qty > 0),
  primary key (ono,pno));
```

ODETAILS Table

[image]

Now I'm trying to figure out the highest and lowest selling product. Logically `PNO 10601` which has the highest `QTY` of 4 is the highest selling product. the following query returns the highest selling product.

```
SELECT PNO FROM 
(SELECT od.PNO, SUM(od.QTY) AS TOTAL_QTY
FROM ODETAILS od 
GROUP BY od.PNO 
ORDER BY SUM(od.QTY) DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM =1

--Thanks to Bob Jarvis
```

How do I add a `DATE` `WHERE` clause to the SQL above so that I can find out the highest selling product for a given month(lets say DECEMBER) ? The `DATE` that I'm referring to is from `ORDERS` table and `RECEIVED` attribute. I guess I need to join the tables first as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93d0c/14)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table orders (
  ono      number(5) not null primary key,
  cno      number(5),
  eno      number(4),
  received date,
  shipped  date
);

INSERT INTO orders
SELECT 1020, 1, 1, DATE '2015-12-21', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1021, 1, 1, DATE '2015-12-20', DATE '2015-12-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022, 1, 1, DATE '2015-12-18', DATE '2015-12-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1023, 1, 1, DATE '2015-12-21', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1024, 1, 1, DATE '2015-12-20', DATE '2015-12-20' FROM DUAL;

create table odetails (
  ono      number(5) not null references orders(ono),
  pno      number(5) not null,
  qty      integer check(qty > 0),
  primary key (ono,pno)
);

INSERT INTO odetails
SELECT 1020, 10506, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1020, 10507, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1020, 10508, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1020, 10509, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1021, 10601, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022, 10601, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022, 10701, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1023, 10800, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1024, 10900, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1 - The `ono`and `pno`s for the `pno` which has sold the maximum total quantity in December 2015**:

```
SELECT ono,
       pno,
       TOTAL_QTY
FROM (
  SELECT q.*,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY TOTAL_QTY DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   (
    SELECT od.ono,
           od.PNO,
           SUM( od.QTY ) OVER ( PARTITION BY od.PNO ) AS TOTAL_QTY
    FROM   ODETAILS od
           INNER JOIN
           orders o
           ON ( o.ono = od.ono )
    WHERE  TRUNC( o.received, 'MM' ) = DATE '2015-12-01'
--    WHERE  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM o.received ) = 12
  ) q
)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Change the `WHERE` clause to get the results for any December rather than just December 2015.

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93d0c/14/0)**:

```
|  ONO |   PNO | TOTAL_QTY |
|------|-------|-----------|
| 1021 | 10601 |         5 |
| 1022 | 10601 |         5 |
```

**Query 2 - The `ono` and `pno`s for the items which have sold the maximum quantity in a single order in December 2015**:

```
SELECT ono,
       pno,
       qty
FROM (
  SELECT od.*,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY od.qty DESC ) AS qty_rank
  FROM   ODETAILS od
         INNER JOIN
         orders o
         ON ( o.ono = od.ono )
  WHERE  TRUNC( o.received, 'MM' ) = DATE '2015-12-01'
  --    WHERE  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM o.received ) = 12
)
WHERE qty_rank = 1
```

Change the `WHERE` clause to get the results for any December rather than just December 2015.

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93d0c/14/1)**:

```
|  ONO |   PNO | QTY |
|------|-------|-----|
| 1021 | 10601 |   4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
... where received between to_date('12/01/2015','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('12/31/2015','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have solved it!

```
SELECT PNO  
FROM (SELECT OD.PNO, SUM(OD.QTY) AS TOTAL_QTY 
      FROM ODETAILS OD INNER JOIN ORDERS ON OD.ONO = ORDERS.ONO
      WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDERS.RECEIVED) = &MONTH_NUMBER 
      GROUP BY OD.PNO 
      ORDER BY SUM(OD.QTY) DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM =1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add some `to_char` calls to your query on the date columns to parse out year and month, or just month if you want all years divided by month (month and year seems more useful), then add that to your where clause. See my self-contained example:

```
with odetails as
(
   select 1 as ono, 1 as pno, 4 as qty from dual
   union all
   select 1 as ono, 2 as pno, 1 as qty from dual
   union all
   select 1 as ono, 3 as pno, 2 as qty from dual
   union all
   select 1 as ono, 4 as pno, 1 as qty from dual
   union all
   select 2 as ono, 2 as pno, 1 as qty from dual
   union all
   select 2 as ono, 3 as pno, 2 as qty from dual
),
orders as
(
    select 1 as ono, 1 as cno, 1 as eno, to_date('2015-10-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as received, to_date('2015-10-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as shipped from dual
    union all 
    select 2 as ono, 1 as cno, 1 as eno, to_date('2015-11-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as received, to_date('2015-11-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as shipped from dual
)
select pno
from
(
   select od.pno, Sum(od.qty) as total_qty,  to_char(received, 'YYYY-MM') as year_month
   from odetails od
   join orders o 
   on o.ono = od.ono
   group by od.pno, to_char(received, 'YYYY-MM')
   order by Sum(od.qty) desc
)
where rownum = 1
and year_month = '2015-11'
;
```

This gives you PNO of 3, since it has the highest quantity in november of 2015.